# Scroll the content inside the collapse menu Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find an easy solution to propose a scroll of the content from the collapse menu when it's collapsed on mobile. I mean, i would like to propose first a scroll of the collapse menu than the body, when the menu is open.

Is there any tip in CSS for this thing? Or only JS script?

[Here is my link](http://bp-design.fr/DocVisio/dashboard.html) (please check in mobile view)

My HTML code :

```
 <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NavbarCollapse" class="nav-link navbar-toggler hidden-md-up"><span class="icon-menu"></span></a>

<div class="row">
                      <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm hidden-md-up col-xs-12" id="NavbarCollapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                          <li class="nav-item active col-xs-12"><a href="#">Tableau de bord</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12"><a href="#">Mon agenda</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12"><a href="#">Messagerie<span class="label label-primary label-pill">17</span></a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12"><a href="#">Mes patients</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12"><a href="#">Activité</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12"><a href="#">Mon cabinet virtuel</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12"><a href="#">Informations administratives</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12"><a href="#">Informations bancaires</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12"><a href="#">Informations profil</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12"><a href="#">Aide</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12"><a href="#">Déconnexion</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Hope my question is clear for you guys.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a scrolling ability to the sidebar nav.

```
#NavbarCollapse{
   max-height: 50vh;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Amazing!! Good job. This solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a fixed height on the UL and enable overflow:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
{
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

If you just want full height:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
{
    height: 60vh;  // The rest of your display is 30-40% on smaller heights
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

If you want it to adjust to the size of the screen dynamically, you will need to set the height on window resize instead.

Comment: thanks it works. Btw, no solution without fixed height ?